# Database Scripts Packaging by Release

Tags: sql, svn, scripting, packaging

I am considering a database packaging policy for our solution. Basically the most common solution seems to maintain a base-line script package, and a series of DDL alter scripts.

Example :

1. You run 1 or many scripts representing you database at version 0.
2. You run a series of alter scripts for changes in the model.

My Question is concerning phase 2:
Almost always every one talks about running on script per change. However I wonder is there any particular draw-backs if we have a script package per release/version?

I.e.

1. You run the baseline script/s
2. For each version you have a script representing the DDL changes incorporated in that particular version.

Any opinions are greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Baubak

I hope that

Answer (score 2):

You can feel free to run many scripts per release but you should take of their order and it's better to encapsulate all related changes into single file.

Development scripts can differs from release scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you have to take care that its clear in what order the scripts in your package are run.

e.G. if you change a view to include a new column, that column must exist before you change the view.

I do it that way (having files that start with the order number in which they must be called)

Answer (score 0):

And thanks for your answers. After some discussions and use case studies we arrived at the solution of small update scripts for each version instead of a big release script. This is because we do not want to run all change scripts all the time, and often as developer you will just want to just update your work data base to be in synch with the release branch.

I greatly thank you for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: please mark either your own answer or one of the other (the one that helped you most) as 'accepted' (the hollow hook on the left, below the voting)  so this question is marked as resolved.